# How to fix a disappeared addons tab in user pref. menu?

Tags: python, scripting, customization

I was watching a video on how to script an addon. When I loaded my script, the addons tab menu disappeared. In the script in the bl_info properties I deleted the

- "warning": "",
- "wiki_url": "",
- "category": "Add Mesh",

I have tried reloading factory settings, but it did not help. I know reinstalling probably would help, but isn't there another way ?

[image]

This is the script I used for adding an object into the scene:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Head mesh",
    "author": "sensim",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 78, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > Basic head mesh",
    "description": "Adds a new basic head mesh"

    }


import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector

def add_object(self, context):


    verts = [Vector((-1.1349272727966309, -1.7702020406723022, -1.0)), Vector((-1.0, -1.0, 0.7697991132736206)), Vector((-1.1349272727966309, 1.7702020406723022, -1.0)), Vector((-1.0, 1.0, 0.7697991132736206)), Vector((1.1349272727966309, -1.7702020406723022, -1.0)), Vector((1.0, -1.0, 0.7697991132736206)), Vector((1.1349272727966309, 1.7702020406723022, -1.0)), Vector((1.0, 1.0, 0.7697991132736206)), Vector((0.34025609493255615, -0.34025609493255615, -0.19741106033325195)), Vector((-0.34025609493255615, -0.34025609493255615, -0.19741106033325195)), Vector((-0.34025609493255615, 0.34025609493255615, -0.19741106033325195)), Vector((0.34025609493255615, 0.34025609493255615, -0.19741106033325195)), Vector((1.0, -1.0, 1.5482919216156006)), Vector((1.0, 1.0, 1.5482919216156006)), Vector((-1.0, 1.0, 1.5482919216156006)), Vector((-1.0, -1.0, 1.5482919216156006)), Vector((0.6152846813201904, -0.6152846813201904, 2.309370517730713)), Vector((-0.6152846813201904, -0.6152846813201904, 2.309370517730713)), Vector((0.6152846813201904, 0.6152846813201904, 2.309370517730713)), Vector((-0.6152846813201904, 0.6152846813201904, 2.309370517730713)), Vector((1.0, 0.308607816696167, 0.7697991132736206)), Vector((1.0, -0.308607816696167, 0.7697991132736206)), Vector((0.839706540107727, -0.2591400146484375, 0.5348026752471924)), Vector((0.839706540107727, 0.2591400146484375, 0.5348026752471924)), Vector((1.0, -0.308607816696167, 1.5482919216156006)), Vector((1.0, 0.308607816696167, 1.5482919216156006)), Vector((0.8649244904518127, 0.2669224739074707, 1.8155105113983154)), Vector((0.8649244904518127, -0.2669224739074707, 1.8155105113983154)), Vector((1.6463451385498047, 0.308607816696167, 0.7697991132736206)), Vector((1.6463451385498047, -0.308607816696167, 0.7697991132736206)), Vector((1.6463451385498047, -0.308607816696167, 0.9704011678695679)), Vector((1.6463451385498047, 0.308607816696167, 0.9704011678695679)), Vector((0.9206359386444092, -0.5034536123275757, 1.682616114616394)), Vector((0.8917638659477234, -0.7121753692626953, 1.8081958293914795)), Vector((0.8304011821746826, -0.670590877532959, 1.9223713874816895)), Vector((0.7614514231681824, 0.5765117406845093, 2.0202102661132812)), Vector((0.9254456162452698, 0.7405059933662415, 1.6957820653915405)), Vector((0.8664040565490723, -0.41031914949417114, 1.7657757997512817)), Vector((0.8678664565086365, 0.4280139207839966, 1.8096904754638672)), Vector((0.9254456162452698, 0.4457833170890808, 1.6957820653915405)), Vector((0.6621315479278564, -0.49928683042526245, 1.7157901525497437)), Vector((0.6621315479278564, -0.6392937302589417, 1.7157901525497437)), Vector((0.5842267274856567, -0.5613888502120972, 1.8699086904525757)), Vector((0.5842267274856567, 0.5613888502120972, 1.8699086904525757)), Vector((0.6621315479278564, 0.6392937302589417, 1.7157901525497437)), Vector((0.6347787976264954, -0.49084553122520447, 1.769901990890503)), Vector((0.6347787976264954, 0.49084553122520447, 1.769901990890503)), Vector((0.6621315479278564, 0.49928683042526245, 1.7157901525497437)), Vector((1.0, -0.6543039083480835, 1.5482919216156006)), Vector((1.0, -0.6543039083480835, 0.7697991132736206)), Vector((0.7401045560836792, -0.44110357761383057, 2.0624403953552246)), Vector((0.7401045560836792, 0.44110357761383057, 2.0624403953552246)), Vector((1.0, 0.6543039083480835, 0.7697991132736206)), Vector((0.5899813175201416, 0.2996980547904968, 0.16869580745697021)), Vector((1.0, 0.6543039083480835, 1.5482919216156006)), Vector((0.5899813175201416, -0.2996980547904968, 0.16869580745697021)), Vector((0.9319220781326294, -0.6377922296524048, 1.7014949321746826)), Vector((0.7940413951873779, -0.5443528890609741, 1.9580446481704712)), Vector((0.8146589398384094, 0.5022628307342529, 1.9149503707885742)), Vector((0.9254456162452698, 0.5931446552276611, 1.6957820653915405)), Vector((0.6621315479278564, -0.569290280342102, 1.7157901525497437)), Vector((0.6095027923583984, -0.526117205619812, 1.8199052810668945)), Vector((0.6095027923583984, 0.526117205619812, 1.8199052810668945)), Vector((0.6621315479278564, 0.569290280342102, 1.7157901525497437)), Vector((0.457908034324646, 0.1799527108669281, -0.02492871880531311)), Vector((0.457908034324646, -0.1799527108669281, -0.02492871880531311)), Vector((0.7220546007156372, 0.1370525062084198, 0.36232033371925354)), Vector((0.7220546007156372, -0.1370525062084198, 0.36232033371925354)), Vector((0.5899813175201416, 0.15850260853767395, 0.16869580745697021)), Vector((0.5899813175201416, -0.15850260853767395, 0.16869580745697021)), Vector((0.7715945839881897, 0.1799527108669281, -0.013859517872333527)), Vector((0.7715945839881897, -0.1799527108669281, -0.013859517872333527)), Vector((0.6496176719665527, 0.15850260853767395, 0.1365136206150055)), Vector((0.6496176719665527, -0.15850260853767395, 0.1365136206150055)), Vector((0.3584824204444885, 0.1370525062084198, 0.3188619315624237)), Vector((0.3584824204444885, -0.1370525062084198, 0.3188619315624237)), Vector((0.22640913724899292, 0.15850260853767395, 0.12523742020130157)), Vector((0.22640913724899292, -0.15850260853767395, 0.12523742020130157)), Vector((0.8025145530700684, -0.35401302576065063, 1.93897545337677)), Vector((0.8100641965866089, -0.428521066904068, 1.8883529901504517)), Vector((0.6221407651901245, -0.5084813833236694, 1.7949036359786987)), Vector((0.8025145530700684, 0.35401302576065063, 1.93897545337677)), Vector((0.841262698173523, 0.46513837575912476, 1.8623204231262207)), Vector((0.6221407651901245, 0.5084813833236694, 1.7949036359786987))]

    edges = []
    faces = [[9, 1, 3, 10], [10, 3, 7, 11], [53, 52, 20, 23], [8, 5, 1, 9], [2, 6, 4, 0], [2, 10, 11, 6], [3, 1, 15, 14], [0, 9, 10, 2], [4, 8, 9, 0], [14, 15, 17, 19], [7, 3, 14, 13], [6, 11, 8, 4], [81, 78, 27, 26], [1, 5, 12, 15], [16, 18, 19, 17], [15, 12, 16, 17], [13, 14, 19, 18], [48, 49, 21, 24], [23, 20, 21, 22], [20, 25, 31, 28], [24, 25, 26, 27], [52, 54, 25, 20], [53, 23, 66, 68], [81, 26, 38, 82], [49, 55, 22, 21], [24, 27, 37, 32], [29, 28, 31, 30], [24, 21, 29, 30], [21, 20, 28, 29], [25, 24, 30, 31], [38, 39, 47, 46], [82, 38, 46, 83], [26, 25, 39, 38], [16, 12, 33, 34], [48, 24, 32, 56], [54, 13, 36, 59], [50, 16, 34, 57], [13, 18, 35, 36], [51, 81, 82, 58], [58, 82, 83, 62], [36, 35, 43, 44], [56, 32, 40, 60], [59, 36, 44, 63], [57, 34, 42, 61], [32, 37, 45, 40], [34, 33, 41, 42], [79, 57, 61, 80], [39, 59, 63, 47], [33, 56, 60, 41], [37, 79, 80, 45], [27, 78, 79, 37], [78, 50, 57, 79], [25, 54, 59, 39], [12, 48, 56, 33], [35, 58, 62, 43], [5, 8, 55, 49], [18, 51, 58, 35], [22, 55, 69, 67], [7, 13, 54, 52], [12, 5, 49, 48], [18, 16, 50, 51], [11, 7, 52, 53], [67, 69, 77, 75], [69, 65, 71, 73], [55, 8, 65, 69], [23, 22, 67, 66], [11, 53, 68, 64], [8, 11, 64, 65], [71, 70, 72, 73], [68, 69, 73, 72], [64, 68, 72, 70], [65, 64, 70, 71], [77, 76, 74, 75], [66, 67, 75, 74], [69, 68, 76, 77], [68, 66, 74, 76], [51, 50, 78, 81]]

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name="New Object Mesh")
    mesh.from_pydata(verts, edges, faces)
    # useful for development when the mesh may be invalid.
    # mesh.validate(verbose=True)
    object_data_add(context, mesh, operator=self)


class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new head mesh object"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_basic_head"
    bl_label = "Add head mesh object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}


    def execute(self, context):

        add_object(self, context)

        return {'FINISHED'}


# Registration

def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        OBJECT_OT_add_object.bl_idname,
        text="Add head mesh object",
        icon='PLUGIN')


# This allows you to right click on a button and link to the manual
def add_object_manual_map():
    url_manual_prefix = "http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/"
    url_manual_mapping = (
        ("bpy.ops.mesh.add_object", "Modeling/Objects"),
        )
    return url_manual_prefix, url_manual_mapping


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.utils.register_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.utils.unregister_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

edit2: also getting this error message if i try the script.[image]

Comment: Please provide the script that leaded to this happening

Comment: Please paste the script here http://pasteall.org/ as the link you provided required signup and no one here will do this as you need to help others help you

Comment: what OS are you using and what blender version are you using as well?

Comment: Blender 2.78 in Windows 10

Comment: Same, I'm using the same version and win7. Please download blender from here http://mirror.cs.umn.edu/blender.org/release/Blender2.78/blender-2.78a-windows64.zip and install your script and see if it is working

Comment: tried reinstalling and also tried using this zipped version none helped

Comment: so could you please say the detailed steps you did after downloading the folder from the link I sent you?

Comment: I unzipped it and opened it. Then I went to user preferences menu and then the addons submenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out that it is a bug. There is no other way to fix this unless you reinstall blender. After you uninstall you must also delete all the registry entries (windows button + R -> regedit -> edit -> find -> look for "blender" -> delete all found blender related entries ). Also delete all the left over data from '\program files', '\documents'. Then in file explorer fileline enter '%appdata%' and check for Blender file left overs. Delete them if you find any. Then install blender again. Don't forget to save your preferences and keybind configs!

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing the script and it worked for me as shown below and I still have the addons showing in the user preferences. Try to download blender from [here](http://mirror.cs.umn.edu/blender.org/release/Blender2.78/blender-2.78a-windows64.zip) and install your script and it should work.

[image]

Comment: perhaps I need to delete the registry files or everything Blender related in my computer, because neither using the version you've provided neither uninstalling and installing helps ?

Comment: @Sensimas so when you downloaded the folder then opened blender then user preferences nothing was in the addon tab? Even without running the script?

Comment: That is right. It was a blank window with or without script. Also when I tried opening the script, I got an error message ( picture in the first post)

Answer (score 1):

Do not delete Blender, go to your %appdata% folder and to this path

```
C:\Users\[INSERT USER ACCOUNT HERE]\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons
```

and delete the offending script, reload Blender or hit refresh and it should come back.